# Difference betweern SQLAlchemys .first() and .fetchone()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering what is the difference between these two? I often see people use .fetchone() where I would just put .first(). Are they the same? If not, is one faster than the other?

Comment: They are from different APIs. `first()` is part of the SQLAlchemy Query API, `fetchone()` is part of the database adapter's Cursor API.

Comment: sqlachemy has a [`fetchone()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.fetchone) of its own that works just like the one in the cursor API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`first()` - will give you the first row and then close. It will not give you the second row ever.

`fetchone()` will give you the first row, but it you call it again it will give you second row, then the third row, etc... Once all rows have been *fetched* it will return `None`.

Here's an example from the MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) (NOTE: sqlalchemy fetchone() calls cursor.fetchone()):

```
# Using a while loop
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
  print(row)
  row = cursor.fetchone()
```

If you only want the first row use `first()`. If you want all the rows but only one at a time, use `fetchone()`.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you. So if fetchone() just stays open, does it impact performance in any way?

Comment: Intuitively, `first()` will be more performant than `fetchone()`. To what extent I can't really say since it probably depends heavily on how much data is in your database. If you are asking if you should replace `fetchone()` with `first()` in existing code...I would try it in a few spots and profile it. Then gauge whether the increase in performance is worth the risk of updating the existing code.